# Passing messages between servers with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm researching ways to pass messages between node.js server.

I was thinking about using hook.io. But hook.io is now dead. What are some alternatives to hook.io? Preferably the alternatives would be in node userland to keep things simple.

Thanks

Comment: This might be of interest to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018888/socket-io-connect-from-one-server-to-another and this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965072/node-js-connecting-to-a-server-using-sockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I think a message queue might be a good idea. Which message queue you are going to use depends on your requirements - fault tolerence, transaction support, ...

Interesting to know is that there is a standard for message queues: [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/) - the *Advanced Message Queueing Protocol*. If you are going with a message queue that supports AMQP you can easily switch implementations without adjusting your code.

A module you probably want to check out is [node-amqp](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp) which allows you to connect to any AMQP-based message queue.

I run [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) with it and I'm confident so far. In case you are hosting your Node.js application on Heroku: [CloudAMQP](http://www.cloudamqp.com/) offers hosted RabbitMQ services that integrate with Heroku.

If you prefer a solution written completely in Node.js, check out [Kue](http://learnboost.github.com/kue/) by TJ Holowaychuk - it's a great message queue backed by Redis.